# How to save and load a HashMap<String,Object>?

Tags: java, dictionary, load, hashmap, save

HashMap

```
public Map<String, BarrackData> barrack = new HashMap<String, BarrackData>();
```

BarrackData.java

```
public class BarrackData {
int A;
int B;
int C;
int D;
int E;
String Title;

public BarrackData(int a, int b, int c, int d, int e, String title) {
    A = a;
    B = b;
    C = c;
    D = d;
    P = p;
    Title = title;
}
```

How can I save this HashMap?
And load it?
I tried different methodes with Objectin/outputstream,
it ended up with NotSerializable, ObjectSteam and IO exception,
Where i have no clue how to deal with them.

Comment: To be fair, it isn't `Serializable`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only `Serializable` classes may be serialized: Just add `implements Serializable` to your class:

```
public class BarrackData implements Serializable {
```

Note that to actually *be* serialized, all fields within the class must be `Serializable`, however java primitives, arrays (if the element type is `Serializable`), `java.lang` classes (like `String`) and `Collections` (if the element type is `Serializable`) are `Serializable`, so you're OK.

Comment: Thanks for helping, When I try to implement Serializable, Eclipse ask to add a Serial version ID or @SuppressWarnings("serial"). So I'm not understanding what I must choose and why.

Comment: You don't need that serial version id. That's there to protect you from deserializing after changing your class field types/number (Assuming you also change the serial version id). Ignore it if you want - it's safe

Answer (score 0):

You must make your Object class serializable (give it serialize() and deserialize() methods which convert it to/from a string or some such that can be saved/loaded). Apparently, HashMaps facilitate some level of serialization out of the box.

Here is a link to a tutorial on Java serialization: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_serialization.htm

and here is some more detailed info on HashMap serialization:
[Serializing and deserializing a map with key as string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2747819/serializing-and-deserializing-a-map-with-key-as-string)

As Bohemian mentioned, implementing `Serializable` is the standard way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

To complete answers, pay attention to the fact that the outcome of `keySet()` belonging to `HashMap` (if you need it at any time) is not `Serializable`.

Indeed, keys aren't supposed to be dissociated from values concerning an `HashMap`.