# Best way to store data for each day in Android?

Tags: android, calendar

I need to display a calendar to the user of my app, there is a default rate (int) for each day and when he/she selects a date give an option to customize the rate (int) for that day.

To display the calendar I am using https://github.com/prolificinteractive/material-calendarview

To store the rate for each day :

A different variable stores the general rate for each day until the user overrides it.

Where I am confused is what's the best way to store this kind of data ? Can I use http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/java/util/Calendar.html ? If so can you point me to a tutorial or something

Comment: my opinion use **SQLITE** to store data

Comment: A database would be overkill for a small set of values. All depends on the amount of data which the Question does not specify. Given human input on an Android device using each specific date one-by-one, I suspect the data would have few entries.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know Android, but in Java…

## Map

My first thought is to create a [Map](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) with the date object as key and the override `int` as value. Probably a [SortedMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/SortedMap.html). See the [Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/map.html).

> Map:  date  →  integer

You can loop or query the date keys to apply their values to your calendar.

In a Collection, you will need to use an [`Integer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html) object rather than an `int` primitive. [Auto-boxing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html) will do that conversion work for you.

## Serialization

Then [serialize](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serialization) that Map to storage every time it is edited, that is, every time the user overrides the default rate. Or do so when your app quits.

When launching your app, restore the Map from storage.

You could serialize by using [Java Serialization](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/serialization/index.html) if supported in Android. See this Question, [Serializing and deserializing a map with key as string](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2747819/642706).

But I would just write a plain text file. The [Apache Commons CSV](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-csv/) library handles the grunt work of reading/writing [Tab-delimited files (TDF)](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tab-separated_values) or [CSV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values) files.

I suggest writing your date values to strings using the sensible and standard format of [ISO 8601](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601): `YYYY-MM-DD`.

Tip: Consider using a `LocalDate` object from Joda-Time or the backport of java.time instead of java.util.Date/.Calendar as the key.

## Time Zone

Be aware that the meaning of a date depends on time zone. For example, a new day dawns earlier in Paris than in Montréal where it is still ‘yesterday’. If the context of your app goes beyond one default time zone, you may need to record the time zone applicable when your user was making her choices about overrides.

## Database

If you had a zillion values that do not need to all be in memory, then use a database such [H2](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/H2_(DBMS)) or SQLite.

For a small set of data, use the Map + serialization described above.