# How to retrieve word after specific word in Java?

Tags: java, regex, pattern-matching

I've this kind of `String`:

```
{aa=bbbb, cc=blabla1, ee=ffff, cc=blabla2, gg=hhhh, cc=blabla3,.......}
```

and i want to get a list of all words after `cc=`.

How can i do it? I'm not very confident with regex stuff.

Comment: Was it a map or properties object?

Comment: ìt's a map objects and then i use mymap.get("mykey") to return a list (that i use as a string by toString() method)

Comment: Can you show what you have tried and where the problem in your code that you think causing the issue?

Comment: How did you get that `String`? From serializing a `Map`? If so you just have to deserialize it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2747819/serializing-and-deserializing-a-map-with-key-as-string

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String input = "aa=bbbb, cc=blabla1, ee=ffff, cc=blabla2, gg=hhhh, cc=blabla3";
    String[] splitValues = input.split(", ");
    Map<String,List<String>> results = new Hashtable<>();
    List<String> valueList = null;
    // iterate through each key=value adding to the results
    for (String a : splitValues) {
         // a = "aa=bbbb"  etc
         String[] keyValues = a.split("=");
         // you can check if values exist. This assumes they do.
         String key = keyValues[0];
         String value = keyValues[1];
         // if it is already in map, add to its value list
         if (results.containsKey(key)) {
            valueList = results.get(key);
            valueList.add(value);
          } else {
            valueList = new ArrayList<>();
            valueList.add(value);
            results.put(key, valueList);
          }
        }

         System.out.println("cc= values");
         valueList = results.get("cc");
         // assumes value is in results
         for (String a : valueList)
            System.out.println(a);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is very vague but I am guessing the String is provided as is, like:

```
String toSearch = "{aa=bbbb, cc=blabla1, ee=ffff, cc=blabla2, gg=hhhh, cc=blabla3,.......}";
```

By list I am guessing you are referring to the abstract List object and not to an array. Here is a solution:

```
String toSearch = "{aa=bbbb, cc=blabla1, ee=ffff, cc=blabla2, gg=hhhh, cc=blabla3,.......}";
List<String> result = new ArrayList<String>();
int prevMatch = 0;
while (toSearch.indexOf("cc=", prevMatch+1) != -1) {
    result.add(toSearch.substring( // Substring method.
               toSearch.indexOf("cc=",prevMatch+1)+3,toSearch.indexOf(",") //Getting correct indexes.
               ));
               prevMatch = toSearch.indexOf("cc=",prevMatch+1);
}
```

The prevMatch variable ensures that the indexOf("cc=") that will be returned will be the next one occurring in the String. For the above String the returning ArrayList will contain the words "blabla1","blabla2", "blabla3" and whatever else is encountered.